# How to mimic a global variable?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Say I have a recursive function:

```
void Part(some args)
{
    int static count=0;
    if(condition)
        count++;
    else if(condition)
        return;
    else
        Part(different args)
}
```

Basically, I want to see how many times a condition is satisfied during the entire function call. But, how can I return this count to the `main()` function? I used a global function and it worked fine, but some people say it's bad practice. I don't think I can use a normal return by value since it's a recursive function. So, is there a better way?

I first tried to change the function to return by value and added `return count` at the very end, so that the final count will be returned. But it didn't work since I already have a blank `return` statement within the function to manually stop the control.

Comment: I would use a global variable (assuming that this is just some kind of instrumentation, rather than the real purpose of the function). But if you don't want a global variable then pass a reference to a variable into the function. `void Part(some args, int& count)`

Comment: Since the function is `void` you could just make it `int` and `return count;`

Comment: `if(condition) else if(condition)` - the second `if` `condition` is very likely never `true`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think they might be `some condition` and `different condition` like `some args` and `different args`.

Comment: @273K You are most likely correct :-) I was hoping OP would make a better example of "the real thing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have written your recursion, your loop will end as soon as your desired counting condition is met, or an ending condition is met.  You are only looping as long as both conditions are not met.  In which case, your `count` will never be more than `1` at most.  If you really want to count multiple conditions without stopping, use something more like this instead:

```
int Part(some args)
{
    if (some end condition)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1 + Part(different args);
}

...

int count = Part(args);
```

On the other hand, if you want to keep using the code you have shown, but don't want to use a global variable (don't use a `static` local variable, otherwise you can never call your function more than once, since you won't be able to ever reset the variable back to 0), then use an output parameter instead, eg:

```
void Part(some args, int &count)
{
    if (some condition)
        ++count;
    else if (some other condition)
        return;
    else
        Part(different args, count);
}

int Part(some args)
{
    int count = 0;
    Part(args, count);
    return count;
}

...

int count = Part(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int Part(some args, int count = 0)
{
   if (some condition)
       return count + 1;
   else if (different condition)
       return count;
   else
       return Part(different args, count);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << Part(some args) << "\n";
}
```